# How do I add multiple traces/trendlines each with a subset of data onto a single scatterplot in R using plotly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot, plotly

In the `plotly` package, I am using the `ggplot()` function and `ggplotly()` function. I want to create a scatterplot with the amount of CWD on the x-axis and the amount of Lawn on the y-axis. There should be three lines per scatterplot reflecting a linear relationship for each year (2013, 2014, 2015). Each year has 10 points for Lawn and 10 points for CWD. As sample of my data is below:

```
    Year CWD Lawn
 1  2013   0  420
 2  2013   6  390
 3  2013  14  410
 4  2013  12  349
 5  2013   3  348
 6  2013  46  354
 7  2013 121  311
 8  2013  56  381
 9  2013  42  386
 10 2013  26  381
 11 2014   2  121
 12 2014   2  163
 13 2014   3  298
```

And here is the code I'm using:

```
library(plotly)

### Amount of Lawn versus Amount of CWD
fit<-lm(Lawn~CWD,data=data)
lawn <- ggplot(data, aes(x=CWD, y=Lawn, colour=Year)) + geom_point()
ggplotly()
add_trace(data=data, x = CWD, y = fitted(fit), mode = "lines")
```

I know that the above code is incorrect because it only fits one line onto the graph without considering year. I have tried to use `geom_abline` but I dont know how to extract a subset of data within this function. See below:

[image]

So firstly, how do I plot three traces (one for each year)? Should I be importing my data into R in separate .csv files per year? Surely, there is an easier way to do this within the code.
Secondly, how do I change the colours of the dots and line?

Comment: you can just add `stat_smooth` to your `ggplot` call: `... + stat_smooth(method = "lm")`

Comment: @mtoto, thanks! I used `stat_smooth(method = 'lm',aes(colour = Year), se = FALSE)` and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be within `ggplot` itself, using `geom_smooth` to do the regression for you:

```
lawn <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=CWD, y=Lawn, colour=factor(Year))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE)
```

Note that I've name the data `dat`, since `data` is a function in R.

With you sample data:

[image]

In regards to color, have a look at `?scale_colour_discrete`.

Comment: Good answer. But one related question. How could you put multiple trendlines if the "color" variable is continuous and not a factor, so the colors appear in a gradient. I basically would like to set on line for different subsets that are specified. Thanks!

Comment: Make a new variable with your different subsets. Map color to that new variable.